# Замена с помощью sed или другой подходящий вариант

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Пять каталогов в каждом файл index.html необходимо заменить title.
sed -i '-e s/name/NAME/g' index.html
это то что известно мне, но эту команду необходимо запускать в каждом каталоге.
Как запустить эту команду рекурсивно или depth. Час перебираю варианты не,
получается.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name index.html -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 'ваш_паттерн'
```

Если нужно ограничить вложенность каталогов, используйте `-maxdepth` (1 - текущий каталог, 2 - первый уровень вложенности и т.д.):

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -name index.html -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 'ваш_паттерн'
```

Comment: На OS X не работает, на Linux попаду не скоро.
На OS X даже напрямую sed -i 's/site/mail/g' не меняет.

Comment: @031071, можете поставить реализацию программы *sed* от операционной системы *gnu*: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195590/is-it-possible-to-get-gnu-sed-for-osx // эта реализация «понимает» опцию `-i`